# Set Timeout on Parallel.Foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, parallel.foreach

I have to send a `List` of my custom object(**"Dial"**) to the client from my WCF service.This object has 5 properties:Id,Name,Type,Individual_avg,Dept_avg. The values for Id,Name and Type are coming from a table but the Individual_avg and  dept_avg are coming from a 3rd party service.The requirement is:

1. Load the static properties - Id,Name,Type from a table
2. Call a method within the WCF service that gets the other 2 property values from the 3rd party service.

I have to timeout the call to 3rd party service after 30 seconds.That is,if the service takes more than 30 seconds to respond,I have to send the objects with only the 3 properties fetched from the table(Id,Name,Type) and set the other 2 properties to null. For example,there are 5 `Dials` in the `List`. Spawn 5 threads to call the 3rd party service to get the 2 properties.If the timeout occurs after getting the values for 2 `Dials`,send the `List` with all properties set for these 2 `Dials` and only Id,Name and Type set for the other 3 Dials. I have the following code to achieve it.

```
public DialResponse GetDials(DialRequest req)
{
    DialResponse response = new DialResponse();
    var indiDials = new List<DialDetails>();
    foreach (var c in indiDialIdToShow)
    {
        var indiObj = _repository.FindQueryable<DashboardDial_Tbl>().Where(p => p.DialId == c.DialIdToShow && p.IsActive == true).Select(p => new DialDetails()
            {
                Id = p.DialId,
                Name = p.DialName,
                Type = p.DialType,
             }).SingleOrDefault();
        indiDials.Add(indiObj);
    }
var timeout = 30000; // 30 seconds
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = new CancellationToken();
token = cts.Token;
var myOptions = new ParallelOptions { CancellationToken = cts.Token };
using (var t = new Timer(_ => cts.Cancel(), null, timeout, -1))
{
    Parallel.ForEach(indiDials, myOptions, c =>
    {
        DialDetails newDial = c;
        ReadConfig(c.Id, userName, ref newDial);
        //send a reference to the "dial" object and set the 2 properties on the object

     });
 }
response.DialsList = indiDials;
}

private void ReadConfig(string userName,ref DialDetails dialObj)
{
   //call the 3rd party service
   dialObj.Individual_avg = serviceResponse.someValue;
   dialObj.dept_avg = serviceResponse.anotherValue;
}
```

To test the "timeout" functionality,I put a `Thread.Sleep(40000)` in `"ReadConfig"` method.This returns an empty list of "Dials" instead of the sending "Dials" with only 3 properties(Id,Name,Type) set. What changes should I make so that this piece of code works as intended?

Answer (score 1):

`ReadConfig` is performing the modifications locally and thus `indiDials` is not updated. You can convert it into a function to return the modified item. Sample code:

```
private DialDetails ReadConfig(string userName,ref DialDetails dialObj)
{
   //call the 3rd party service
   dialObj.Individual_avg = serviceResponse.someValue;
   dialObj.dept_avg = serviceResponse.anotherValue;

   retun dialObj;
}
```

And call it from the loop such that the `List` is modified:

```
indiDials[indiDials.IndexOf(newDial)] = ReadConfig(userName, ref newDial);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. However,the problem is,once the Timeout of 30 seconds is reached,it does not return any object."If the service takes more than 30 seconds to respond,I have to send the objects with only the 3 properties fetched from the table(Id,Name,Type) and set the other 2 properties to null." Currently,it's sending an empty `List` although the Id,Name and Type have been set on the Dials.

Comment: @user1550951 you have set your timeout in the loop and thus it will be applied in the next iteration (in case a connection takes too long). You have to set a timeout also in the connection itself (serviceResponse).

Comment: @user1550951 I don't know the kind of connection you are using. But if you don't "time it out" it will be trying for as long as required and the rest of the code (including your own timeout bit) would be waiting. You have to do some research/ask (a new question) about how to deal with this while setting the connection. The timeout property is part of the basic configuration of any kind of connection (and thus should be pretty straightforward to find this out).